# Layout of Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming" in LaTeX

Tags: book-design, knuth

Just for fun, I want to write something in the same layout as *The Art of Computer Programming* by D.E. Knuth. Does anybody know how to get this layout with LaTeX?

**[EDIT]** I am interested in the full layout, not only the style of the algorithms. Is there a way to use the layout with LaTeX (*not TeX*)? Going through `taocpmac.tex` looks a little bit complicated.

Comment: Hello, Ivo. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: TeX (not LaTeX) macros used by Knuth for that book are available for download [here](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/local/lib/); look for the file called taocpmac.tex.

Comment: This still seems to be exceptionally broad...